# Is Harry Potter considered to be problematic?

Tags: gentiles, books-generally, sorcery-magic-kishuf

Is there any halachic problem with a Jew reading the Harry Potter series? I know some people are against it, so wondering if there are any solid prohibitions involved beyond bittul zman, bittul torah, and it being "nisht".

(If your answer is "no, it's fine" than don't bother, I am looking to see if anyone knows or can think of any real issue)

Comment: I didn't know something being "nisht" was a solid prohibition. In any event can you clarify what's special about Harry Potter that you can't ask about reading fantasy novels in general?

Comment: Based off your parenthetical comment you should edit your question to be "please provide prohibitions involved in reading Harry Potter", since you don't seem to be wondering **if** there are any.

Comment: Apparently, a Haredi person would not waste time on fictional stories, and it would definitely fall under Bitul Torah. Now, can it be strictly prohibited because of imaginary sorcery and magic? I doubt it as nobody would think to apply it in real life.

Comment: @AlBerko only Charedim have the prohibition of bitul torah?

Comment: @robev B"T is technically not a prohibition but a moral choice. It is not punishable. So yes, only Haredim who value Torah study subscribe to it.

Comment: I heard from a gadol back when Harry Potter first came out, that it was starting with little kids, but as they grow to teenagers boy-girl issues will become important. And so it was.

Comment: I assume [@Alex](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/90/harry-potter) has something to say about this

Comment: @AlBerko only Haredim value Torah study?

Comment: @AlBerko eating half an olive of pig also isn't punished. No proof it's not prohibited.

Comment: This is a question that is pretty widespread online - https://www.torahmusings.com/2005/07/reading-harry-potter/ and https://www.aish.com/atr/Harry_Potter_and_the_Jews.html and https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiihsSJq830AhUFoVwKHVX3DjQQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jewishpress.com%2Fjudaism%2Fhalacha-hashkafa%2Fis-it-proper-is-it-appropriate-to-read-works-of-fantasy-say-harry-potter-for-example%2F2020%2F12%2F09%2F&usg=AOvVaw30fZ82Ol7ZBw2mP010UJXl and many others via google...

Comment: Harry Potter is a cult.

Comment: @robev IIRC Less that K'Zais was *exempt* from punishment, the Torah does not give a measure, it's all Rabbinic.

Comment: @AlBerko bittul Torah is also exempt from punishment what's your point

Answer (score 1):

There's no prohibition about reading about magic, since everyone knows that it's just fantasy. There are chapters here and there, though, which are full of immodest conversation and relationships. This is not a concern in the first 3 books, however, in the later ones, especially the fifth, there are such things. Reading these things are probably prohibited. If one skips these parts, which shouldn't be too hard, as they only come up here and there, then I don't see why there would be a problem.

Comment: Welcome to MY and thanks for your first answer. Generally we do not know the reliability of people who post answers here, therefore it is best whenever possible to quote sources. So could you possibly source your assertion of "no prohibition about reading about magic"? (E.g. by quoting what is forbidden with magic). Could you source your view that skipping the parts with immodest conversation and relationships while possessing the book is acceptable? Looking forward to seeing your edits and future posts!